# Segfault error with lists of smart pointers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I'm having segfault issues with my latest project. I've ran my program under valgrind but I'm having difficulty interpreting the output. I've looked at [the manual for valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.errormsgs), but even that doesn't make it clear when a particular error message is a problem or not. For instance, it says, "'Still Reachable' blocks are very common and arguably not a problem," but I'm not experienced enough to differentiate when they're acceptable and when they're not. Could someone please look at my valgrind log and give me some insight as to what's going on with my code, and which of the reported errors are genuine concerns?

[Here's a link to all of my code as well as the valgrind log.](https://github.com/eindacor/BigNum)

To give a brief description of when the segfault occurs during runtime, the program works like this: It takes a string input by the user, and generates a list of "calculator items" which includes numbers, symbols, and parentheses. The program then analyzes the list, and reduces it just as you would by hand. If the equation is 18-(9+4), it will remove "(9+4)", solve for 9+4, then add the solution back into the original list to make it 18-13. My program returns a segfault error after the list has been reduced to a single element. At this point ([line 237 in main.cpp](https://github.com/eindacor/BigNum/blob/master/main.cpp#L237)) it's supposed to verify that the only remaining element is a number, which means that's the final answer, but it won't dereference the iterator. I'm not sure if that helps, because I realize the memory could have been allocated/deallocated incorrectly earlier in the program, but that is where my program fails consistently.

If I need to be more specific about the way my program works I wouldn't mind going into more detail, but I'm not really sure what is relevant or where the problem might be. I should note that I'm very new to smart pointers, and I've had lots of memory issues with those before, so there's a good chance the way I handle memory with those is the culprit. My smart pointer is declared in [bignum_decs.h](https://github.com/eindacor/BigNum/blob/master/bignum_decs.h) as `calc_ptr` and its functions are defined in [bignum_classdefs.cpp](https://github.com/eindacor/BigNum/blob/master/bignum_classdefs.cpp) on line 1410. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're pushing a lot of NULL calc_ptrs onto the stack.
(Using the default constructor:

```
calc_ptr() {stored = NULL;}
```

)

At line 237, you aren't checking to see if the calc_ptr is NULL before you dereference it.

Comment: So, presumably at that point, there's one calc_ptr in the list, so it hits that line of code, for whatever reason, your list has an item created from `cl.push_back(calc_ptr());` or similar, so it's a NULL calc_ptr.  Your code dereferences the valid iterator `if ((*i)->getItemType()==NUMBER)`, but that gives it a calc_ptr whose stored is NULL.

That's my best guess but your code is hard to follow.  Stepping through the code with a debugger to verify this will be your best bet.

Comment: When I originally added `calc_ptr`'s to the list, I had some problems with the stored pointers getting deleted by the list functions (insert, push_back, etc.), so I started adding them as null pointers and immediately assigning that element to an object on the heap. I might have missed an instance where it adds a null `calc_ptr` object without assigning it. I'd like to go back and make sure my copy constructor is tight enough to add/remove items from the list without problem, maybe that would solve this issue as well. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes it is hard to follow, sorry about that. I'm a beginner and this is the most ambitious project I've worked on by a long shot. Once I get it working I plan on refining the code and giving it more structure.

Comment: Right.  If you get a better understanding of the code but still need help, feel free to update and comment here that you've updated the question, so I can see if I can figure anything out.

Valgrind is saying you tried to access memory 0x8, which always ends up being NULL with an offset.  This happens at calcItem::getItemType(), called by swapItems, called by solve, etc.  That's line 237, like you said.  The only problem is you misunderstood why 237 failed.  It's not that it "won't dereference the iterator", it's that the object you're pointing at is uninitialized.